# Comment block indentation before methods in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, coding-style

Every time I try to create a comment block before a method in Swift the cursor goes to first column, like this:

[image: Comment block with wrong indentation.]

This happens with Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7 beta 4.

I'd like it to keep in line with the first asterisk:

[image: Comment block with right indentation.]

That's the way it was with Objective-C:

[image: Comment block with right indentation in Objective-C.]

Is it possible to fix this behaviour?

Comment: I've reported this as a bug: [rdar://21607719](http://www.openradar.me/21607719)